# Duplicate Key error even after using "On Conflict" clause

Tags: postgresql

My table has following structure

```
CREATE TABLE myTable 
(
  user_id       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  task_id       VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  start_time    TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  SOME_COLUMN   VARCHAR,
  col1          INTEGER,
  col2          INTEGER DEFAULT 0
);

ALTER TABLE myTable
   ADD CONSTRAINT pk_4_col_constraint UNIQUE (task_id, user_id, start_time, SOME_COLUMN);

ALTER TABLE myTable
   ADD CONSTRAINT pk_3_col_constraint UNIQUE (task_id, user_id, start_time);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_myTable ON myTable USING btree (task_id);
```

However when i try to insert data into table using

```
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES (...) 
ON CONFLICT (task_id, user_id, start_time) DO UPDATE  
  SET ... --updating other columns except for [task_id, user_id, start_time]
```

I get following error

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_4_col_constraint"
  Detail: Key (task_id, user_id, start_time, SOME_COLUMN)=(XXXXX, XXX, 2021-08-06 01:27:05, XXXXX) already exists.
```

I got the above error when i tried to programatically insert the row. I was successfully able to the execute query successfully via SQL-IDE.

Now i have following questions:

1. How is that possible? When 'pk_3_col_constraint' is ensuring my data is unique at 3 columns, adding one extra column will not change anything. What's happening here?
   I am aware that although my constraint name starts with 'pk' i am using UNIQUE constraint rather than Primary Key constraint(probably a mistake while creating constraints but either way this error shouldn't have occurred)
2. Why didn't i get the error when using SQL-IDE?
3. I read in few articles unique constraint works little different as compared to primary key constraint hence causes this issue at time. If this is known issue is there any way i can replicate this error to understand in more detail.

I am running `PostgreSQL 11.9 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 7.4.0, 64-bit` version Postgres. My programmatic env was a Java AWS Lambda.

I have noticed people have faced this error occasionally in the past.
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/15556-7b3ae3aba2c39c23%40postgresql.org 
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/65AECD9A-CE13-4FCB-9158-23BE62BB65DD%40msqr.us#d05d2bb7b2f40437c2ccc9d485d8f41e but there are conclusions as to why it is happening

Comment: This: `ON CONFLICT (task_id, user_id, start_time)` is only looking for three out of the four columns of `pk_4_col_constraint`. You could have existing column with (1, 2, '08/07/21 11:00', 'test') have a conflict on the first three columns of an `INSERT` row (1, 2, '08/07/21 11:00', 'test') and then the `UPDATE` would set `SOME_COLUMN` to a value of 'test' and you would trip `pk_4_col_constraint`.

Comment: I had a similar hunch. But executing `INSERT INTO myTable VALUES('row1_task_id','row1_user_id','2021-08-08 00:00:00.0','test',1,1)  ON CONFLICT(task_id,user_id,start_time) DO UPDATE SET  SOME_COLUMN='test', col1=myTable.col1+1, col2=myTable.col2+1;` multiple times doesn't result in pk_4_col_constraint violation.

Comment: Is this the exact command structure you are using that throws the error? In other words are using `excluded` or some other `UPDATE` expression for setting the column values? Is there by chance a MixedCase version of the table in the database, something like `select * from "myTable"`?

Comment: No I am using just an update query without any other key words. Also there is no other table with lowercase-uppercase combination of same table name

Comment: You have to add unique sql_constrait, and be sure that you have not a duplicate record

Comment: @khelilimiliana i do have "on conflict" clause to update the record in case of duplicate record. And i have already added unique sql_constraint .

Comment: Can you reliably reproduce the error and if so how? Also, what did you mean by: 'I got the above error when i tried to programatically insert the row.' ?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver no i am not able to reproduce the error. When i said tried to insert row programatically i meant, we have scheduled an AWS lambda which inserts/updates the records. There are approx 500K transactions per hour. However i am seeing ~50 such errors per day